# How to copy and change a mysql column in the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table `topics` with existing data. Now I want to add a column that should have the content of an existing column with additional html.

So column `text` contains 'Plain text'
And the new column 'new_text' should contain '<p>Plain text</p>' afterwards.

I know I can copy fields like this

```
UPDATE topics
SET new_text = text;
```

What I want would be something like this

```
UPDATE topics
SET new_text = '<p>' . text . '</p>;
```

Comment: I wouldn't store markup in the database like that if I were you.  You're combining presentation layer with data layer, which has ramifications https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content  but I think @e4c5's answer tells you how to do it.

Comment: @DanFarrell I also feel the same and I have updated my answer already to reflect that

Comment: I know. But the new field will be a wysiwyg text field. So there will be more html later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

```
UPDATE topics
SET new_text = CONCAT("<p>", `text`, "</p>");
```

Having said that, i am not quite sure if you should be making this change. Once you make the change stripping it out will be very difficult. Wrapping html tags around the content is something that can be done very easily in the application layer. So I think simple HTML tags should be kept out of the table